# move windows 10 to single partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, partitioning

I have a laptop (Dell XPS 15) on which Windows 10 home came preinstalled. I would like to encrypt it, and since Bitlocker is unavailable for the home editions of windows, I'm resorting to Veracrypt.

However, Windows by default came with 4 partitions: the boot partition, the main partition and two recovery partitions. In order for Veracrypt to work, I need to merge the boot partition and main partition.

How should I do this? How can I make windows boot from the same partition that it is installed on? The classic tools seem to fail since the boot partition is involved. I'm willing to reinstall windows if that's what it takes, but buying a new windows installation (this is an OEM version with recovery partition but no install cd) is a bit overkill.

Comment: Don't merge Boot. Windows requires the Boot partition if you're using an EFI BIOS. Without that your computer will no longer work, and there's a chance you won't be able to recover without sending the computer back to Dell.

Comment: No; You don't need to merge the partitions, the boot partition and the system partition have to be separate anyways. Buying Windows wouldn't solve your problem anyone who suggests that isn't worth listening to.  VeraCrypt supports MBR/GPT

Comment: Oh, ok. Then the system encryption must have failed for another reason. Hmm... back to investigation then, thanks for your beedback both!